# UnitTest++ issues: Trying to use a Predicate that has state

Tags: c++, constants

Relevant code, this is from `UnitTest++/TestRunner.h`:

```
class TestRunner
{
public:
    explicit TestRunner(TestReporter& reporter);
    ~TestRunner();

    template <class Predicate>
    int RunTestsIf(TestList const& list, char const* suiteName, 
                   const Predicate& predicate, int maxTestTimeInMs) const
    {
        Test* curTest = list.GetHead();

        while (curTest != 0)
        {
            if (IsTestInSuite(curTest,suiteName) && predicate(curTest))
            {
                RunTest(m_result, curTest, maxTestTimeInMs);
            }

            curTest = curTest->next;
        }

        return Finish();
    }   

private:
    TestReporter* m_reporter;
    TestResults* m_result;
    Timer* m_timer;

    int Finish() const;
    bool IsTestInSuite(const Test* const curTest, char const* suiteName) const;
    void RunTest(TestResults* const result, Test* const curTest, int const maxTestTimeInMs) const;
};
```

Here is my predicate class I am trying to modify to let it do what I want:

```
class ListFilterRemember {
    char **list;
    int n;
    Test **testsAlreadyRun;
    int index_tar;
    int max_allocd;
public:
    ListFilterRemember(char **list_, int count) {
                int testCount = 0;
        Test* curTest = Test::GetTestList().GetHead();
        while (curTest != 0) {
            testCount++;
        }
                list = list_; n = count; max_allocd = testCount;
        testsAlreadyRun = new Test *[max_allocd];
        index_tar = 0;
    }
    bool operator()(const Test* const t) const {
        for (int i=0;i<index_tar;++i) {
            if (testsAlreadyRun[i] == t) { return false; }
        }
        for (int i=0;i<n;++i) {
            std::string dot_cpp_appended = std::string(list[i]) + ".cpp";
            if (!strcasecmp(t->m_details.testName, list[i]) ||
                    !strcasecmp(t->m_details.suiteName, list[i]) ||
                    !strcasecmp(t->m_details.filename, list[i]) ||
                    !strcasecmp(t->m_details.filename, dot_cpp_appended.c_str()) || (
                            filename_dir_prefix_len < (int)strlen(t->m_details.filename) && ( // ensure the ptr arith in next 2 lines doesn't go out of bounds
                                    !strcasecmp(t->m_details.filename+filename_dir_prefix_len, list[i]) ||
                                    !strcasecmp(t->m_details.filename+filename_dir_prefix_len, dot_cpp_appended.c_str())
                            )
                    ) || (
                            std::string::npos != findCaseInsensitive(t->m_details.testName,list[i])
                    )
            ) {
                // erring on the side of matching more tests
                //printf(" running\n");
                if (index_tar >= max_allocd) throw std::runtime_error("Did not allocate! Segfault here.");
                testsAlreadyRun[index_tar] = (Test *)t;
                index_tar += 1;
                return true;
            }
        }
        //printf(" not running\n");
        return false;
    }
    ~ListFilterRemember() {
        delete[] testsAlreadyRun;
    }
};
```

You see the way that it's defined in `TestRunner.h` attaches a const qualifier which makes it impossible for my `operator ()` function to make changes to member variables. I need to make those changes so I can remember which tests I've already run so I don't run them again. The reason why there might be risk of them running again is that I intend to run `RunTestsIf()` multiple times.

I enter a list of tests at the command line to specify which tests I want to run based on their names. That is what all of the string matching code is for. I still want to use those, but this time I want to improve it so that the tests I specify will run in the order that i specify them in. In order to do this I have to move the test runner so that I loop over my specified test list and match based on them one by one.

Ideas? I'd go nuke the const in the UnitTest++ code but I don't want to break things if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `mutable` keyword, but the way the test is structured suggests that the test runner might not reuse the same instance of the predicate, so your changes might be lost between tests.  Of course, if the posted code is the entire test runner, then it looks like it does call the same `Predicate` instance every time.

Comment: I never knew about the `mutable` keyword. Thanks for pointing it out -- it's almost as if it were tailor-made for this situation... I'll have to do some tests to see if there's weird goings on with the Predicate under the hood, but I grepped the src and the bit I posted is the only reference to `"Predicate"`. I could also **probably** edit the src of UnitTest++ slightly to hack it to work but it would most likely require me to recompile it. Just... not good. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd expect a unit test to have a deterministic set of things to test.  This might be closer to an integration test.  Not that that is bad necessarily, just make sure you test the smaller bits first.

That being said, UnitTest++ was designed to be small and easily modified.  I'd extend or wrap it to suit your needs, not break existing functionality though.

Comment: Running my unit test executable without any cmd line args makes it run all tests the usual way. I just figured, hey why not make it do what i want it to do.